# OpenGL ES application crashes when locked screen or entered background

Tags: ios, opengl-es, crash

My application is an OpenGL heavily employed one, which is being used to process images, rendering scenes, display previews, etc. However, after I implemented multi-task as Apple's official document 'OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS', weird crashes still came up sporadically. Debug Navigator Stack trace shows something like 'sgxPatchDeferredFramebufferOffsets', 'presentRenderbuffer EXC_BAD_ACCESS', 'gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient', etc.

So, I would like to know what exactly one should implement OpenGL ES Multi-task.

**=============UPDATE: Problem Solved============**

Thanks for your answer, CStreel, and other guys who tried to help.

After reading 'Background Applications May Not Execute Commands on the Graphics Hardware' part in'OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS' a second time, line by line, I have a new understanding with this issue.

The big problem with my app is I **should not implement OpenGL ES multi-task in a notification method.** Since, unlike delegate methods, notification methods will be called asynchronously, these stopping animation actions and glFinish() calls may not take effect when the application has already moved into the background. This may happen more frequently when I hit the lock-screen button as soon as I am performing a series of OpenGL ES related actions.

If you guys found some other issues, feel free to contact me.

Comment: Problem persists if you call OpenGL ES from serial queue in background. Even after telling the timer to stop firing, a block keeps finishing and it can cause a crash. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215554/how-to-stop-opengl-drawing-when-calling-opengl-from-background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you app is about to enter the background, if your app calls any OGLES functions the OS will kill your app straight away

Read the [App States & Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) for more information
Read the [Being a Responsible Background App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Here are some extracts from that document:

```
(Required) When moving to the background, make sure your app adjusts its behavior appropriately.
```

In regards to OGLES

```
 ...the app should stop calling OpenGL ES functions.
```

Comment: I have implemented these delegates as well as notifications. When application resigned active state, I stopped capture session and animation. I tried to call glfinish() in the processing dispatch queue after resign active notification was received, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Notifications can be synchronous or asynchronous. If you register for notifications specifying an NSOperationQueue, the callback will be asynchronous, otherwise I believe it will always be synchronous.

I had a few of those crashes and found a few bugs in my code:

1. The shared EAGLContext, despite being "multithreaded" was not
   always set on all the threads using it. It seems that you have to
   set the context on the main thread every time it leaves the RunLoop
   to enter your app code and issue any openGL command.
2. iOS 6 needed an extra "glFlush()" when changing buffers, due
   apparently to a bug in iOS 6. iOS 5 and 7 were unaffected.
3. Lack of synchronisation between the "DidEnterBackground" notification and the other code/threads, which meant that the main thread, notifying the app state change was returning early, when other threads were still using openGL. Hold the notification thread until you are finished invoking openGL. Only after it is allowed to return, iOS starts the "watchdog" on openGL.

I use the DidEnterBackground/WillEnterForeground notifications (not callbacks) to stop/restart openGL operations. I still get a very rare crash (I must use automation and lock/unlock/rotate for 20-30 minutes before getting it), but using WillResignActive/DidBecomeActive makes no difference; they happen regardless.